# Has anyone been able to use the Cloud9 IDE on an iPhone 6 Plus? And if so, how did it go?

Tags: cloud9-ide, iphone-6-plus

I am considering purchasing an iPhone 6 Plus and was wondering if anyone has done any programming in the Cloud9 IDE on an iPhone 6 Plus?  I didn't have much success on an older iPad, but it works fine on my 6 year old MAC.